# How can I show/hide toolbar depending on mouse movements and mouse position inside window?

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

Hi Iam using Python and GTK+. In my GUI I have 2 toolbars I want show  first toolbar only if user moves mouse than hide it again after few seconds as for second toolbar I want to show it when user is on particular x,y coordinates.How can I achieve it ?

EDIT:

Iam creating some kind of media player so I want toolbars to disapear while user is not using mouse in case of playerMenu toolbar or if user doesn't move it to specific location in case of ribbonBar toolbar .Iam using GTK+ here is my code for toolbars:

```
class Player(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    def build_UI(self):
        container=Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL)
        ribbonBar=Gtk.Toolbar()
        playerMenu=Gtk.Toolbar()

   def mouse_moved(self):
       #TO-DO here I should check cordinates for example I want to see if mouse.y=window.height-50px and I would like to show ribbonaBar
       #after that Gdk.threads_add_timeout(1000,4000,ribbonBar.hide)

       #TO-DO here I show playerMenu toolbar if mouse is moved
       # smt like playerMenu.show() 
       #after that I would call Gdk.threads_add_timeout(1000,4000,playerMenu.hide)
       # to hide it again after 4 seconds
```

I should connect my window to some mouse event but I don't know the event name and how can I get mouse.x and mouse.y?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this? Trying to use widgets that disappear when you're not moving the mouse is rather annoying, IMHO.

But anyway...

To toggle the visibility of a widget use the show() and hide() methods, or map() and unmap() if you don't want the other widgets in your window to move around. To handle timing, use gobject.timeout_add(), and you'll need to connect() your window to "motion_notify_event" and set the appropriate event masks: gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK and probably gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK. The Event object that your motion_notify callback receives will contain x,y mouse coordinates.

At least, that's how I'd do it in GTK2; I don't know GTK3.

If you want more specific help you need to post some code.

---

I see that you've posted some code, but it doesn't have a lot of detail... But I understand that GTK can be a bit overwhelming. I haven't used it much in the last 5 years, so I'm a bit rusty, but I just started getting into it again a couple of months ago and thought your question would give me some good practice. :)

I won't claim that the code below is the best way to do this, but it works. And hopefully someone who is a GTK expert will come along with some improvements.

This program builds a simple Toolbar with a few buttons. It puts the Toolbar into a Frame to make it look nicer, and it puts the Frame into an Eventbox so we can receive events for everything in the Frame, i.e., the Toolbar and its ToolItems. The Toolbar only appears when the mouse pointer isn't moving and disappears after a few seconds, unless the pointer is hovering over the Toolbar.

This code also shows you how to get and process mouse x,y coordinates.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' A framed toolbar that disappears when the pointer isn't moving
    or hovering in the toolbar.

    A response to the question at
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26272684/how-can-i-show-hide-toolbar-depending-on-mouse-movements-and-mouse-position-insi

    Written by PM 2Ring 2014.10.09
'''

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import gobject

if gtk.pygtk_version < (2, 4, 0):
    print 'pygtk 2.4 or better required, aborting.'
    exit(1)


class ToolbarDemo(object):
    def button_cb(self, widget, data=None):
        #print "Button '%s' %s clicked" % (data, widget)
        print "Button '%s' clicked" % data
        return True

    def show_toolbar(self, show):
        if show:
            #self.frame.show()
            self.frame.map()
        else:
            #self.frame.hide()
            self.frame.unmap()

    def timeout_cb(self):
        self.show_toolbar(self.in_toolbar)
        if not self.in_toolbar:
            self.timer = False
        return self.in_toolbar

    def start_timer(self, interval):
        self.timer = True
        #Timer will restart if callback returns True
        gobject.timeout_add(interval, self.timeout_cb)

    def motion_notify_cb(self, widget, event):
        if not self.timer:
            #print (event.x, event.y)
            self.show_toolbar(True)
            self.start_timer(self.time_interval)
        return True

    def eventbox_cb(self, widget, event):
        in_toolbar = event.type == gtk.gdk.ENTER_NOTIFY
        #print event, in_toolbar
        self.in_toolbar = in_toolbar

        #### self.show_toolbar(in_toolbar) does BAD things :)
        if in_toolbar:
            self.show_toolbar(True)
        return True

    def quit(self, widget): gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        #Is pointer over the toolbar Event box?
        self.in_toolbar = False

        #Is pointer motion timer running?
        self.timer = False

        #Time in milliseconds after point stops before toolbar is hidden
        self.time_interval = 3000


        self.window = win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        width = gtk.gdk.screen_width() // 2
        height = gtk.gdk.screen_height() // 5
        win.set_size_request(width, height)
        win.set_title("Magic Toolbar demo")
        win.set_border_width(10)

        win.connect("destroy", self.quit)
        #self.motion_handler = win.connect("motion_notify_event", self.motion_notify_cb)
        win.connect("motion_notify_event", self.motion_notify_cb)
        win.add_events(gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_MASK |
            gtk.gdk.POINTER_MOTION_HINT_MASK)

        box = gtk.VBox()
        box.show()
        win.add(box)

        #An EventBox to capture events inside Frame,
        # i.e., for the Toolbar and its child widgets.
        ebox = gtk.EventBox()
        ebox.show()
        ebox.set_above_child(True)
        ebox.connect("enter_notify_event", self.eventbox_cb)
        ebox.connect("leave_notify_event", self.eventbox_cb)
        box.pack_start(ebox, expand=False)

        self.frame = frame = gtk.Frame()
        frame.show()
        ebox.add(frame)

        toolbar = gtk.Toolbar()
        #toolbar.set_border_width(5)
        toolbar.show()
        frame.add(toolbar)

        def make_toolbutton(text):
            button = gtk.ToolButton(None, label=text)
            #button.set_expand(True)
            button.connect('clicked', self.button_cb, text)
            button.show()
            return button

        def make_toolsep():
            sep = gtk.SeparatorToolItem()
            sep.set_expand(True)
            #sep.set_draw(False)
            sep.show()
            return sep

        for i in xrange(5):
            button = make_toolbutton('ToolButton%s' % (chr(65+i)))
            toolbar.insert(button, -1)
            #toolbar.insert(make_toolsep(), -1)

        for i in xrange(1, 9, 2):
            toolbar.insert(make_toolsep(), i)

        button = gtk.Button('_Quit')
        button.show()
        box.pack_end(button, False)
        button.connect("clicked", self.quit)

        win.show()
        frame.unmap()


def main():
    ToolbarDemo()
    gtk.main()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Does the toolbar in your fullscreen media player annoys you? :)

Comment: Ok. Good point, Cilyan. However, those toolbars don't disappear while you're hovering over them (or their child widgets), and Haris Kovacevic didn't specify that behaviour in his question... :)

Comment: As I said, the event name you want is "motion_notify_event". But since I'm feeling generous I'll show you how to do the first toolbar. :)

Comment: Ok I give you rep for now If I don't get better answer I'll accept it and thanks a lot for your time to help me out.

Comment: That's ok. It was fun to do; I just wish it wasn't such a chore wading through the GTK docs. Thanks for the points. If you need me to clarify anything in my code, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Ok I'll test it all tonight and let you know about results

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62831/discussion-between-haris-kovacevic-and-pm-2ring).